# linking to directory from script

Tags: bash, shell, rake

I am trying to get a file from a specific directory and having an issue. It says the file is there but doesn't run against the script line by line. But, if I take it out of the folder, it works fine.

I need this to work:

```
while read line
  do
  echo $line
  ...
done <tmp/files/yes.csv
```

But this does work:

```
while read line
  do
  echo $line
  ...
done <yes.csv
```

I am doing a wget to get this file and saving it to a folder but can't seem to find out what is wrong. When I run the script, I get no errors. When I take it out of the folder, the script runs perfectly.

Comment: try specifying the full path name ex. `~/dir/temp/files/yes.csv` or `/usr/username/home/dir/temp/files/yes.csv`

Comment: I tried this as well, no such luck. It does nothing.

Comment: You did change artmees' temp to match your tmp, didn't you?

Comment: Yes rojomoke... Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the exact error you see?